# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile

Tags: maven, plugins, compilation, dependencies

I am trying to compile and install using: mvn clean install deploy but keep getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XcertDA: Could not resolve dependencie
s for project com.companyA.xcert:XcertDA:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
dependencies at com.companyA.xcert:XoShared:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT -> com.evincible
:EvncUtilCore:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.e
vincible:EvncUtilCore:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.evincible:EvincS
ecforms:pom:4.0.1.0-20150527.140858-5 in http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/m
vn/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until
 the update interval of buildserver.companyA.com has elapsed or updates are fo
rced -> [Help 1]
```

I am getting a similar error for quite a few other projects. Is the main file it is trying to find is:

```
  com/evincible/EvincSecforms/4.0.1.0-20150527.140858-5.pom
```

I can see why it has an error as that exact file name and path do not exist on our buildserver? Any help understanding the exact path it is going to and exact name it is scanning for would be very helpful.

```
    My POM.xml

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org  /maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <parent>
     <artifactId>Xcert</artifactId>
     <groupId>com.companyA.xcert</groupId>
     <version>4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
     </parent>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.companyA.xcert</groupId>
     <artifactId>XcertDA</artifactId>
     <name>XcertDA</name>
     <version>4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <description>Xcert Data Access Library</description>
     <build>
     <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </extension>
     </extensions>
     <finalName>XcertDA</finalName>
     <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId> 
                <artifactId>torque-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>4.0</version>              
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal> 
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                         
              <packaging>classpath</packaging>
              <configPackage>com. 
     companyA.common.torque.templates.om</configPackage>

     <!--packaging>directory</packaging>                            
                            <configDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/torque-
     gen</configDir>
                            <configPackage>${project.basedir}/src/main/torque-
     gen</configPackage -->
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/torque
     /schema</sourceDir>
                            <defaultOutputDir>${project.basedir}/src
     /main/java</defaultOutputDir>
                            <defaultOutputDirUsage>none</defaultOutputDirUsage>
                            <projectRootDir>${project.basedir}</projectRootDir>
                            <loglevel>info</loglevel>
                            <options>
                                <torque.om.package>com. 
        companyA.securepass.om</torque.om.package>
                            </options>                  
                        </configuration>                        
                    </execution>
         <execution>
            <id>generate-sql</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <packaging>classpath</packaging>
              <configPackage>org.apache.torque.templates.sql</configPackage>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/torque
         /schema</sourceDir>
              <newFileTargetDir>target/generated-sql</newFileTargetDir>
              <compileNewFileTargetDir>false</compileNewFileTargetDir>
              <compileModifiedFileTargetDir>false</compileModifiedFileTargetDir>
              <options>
                <torque.database>mssql</torque.database>
              </options>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
                </executions>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId>
                    <artifactId>torque-templates</artifactId>
              <version>4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional/>

                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.companyA.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>XoTorqueTemplates</artifactId>
              <version>4.0b</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional/>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId>
            <artifactId>torque-generator</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional/>
      <version>4.0</version>
            </dependency>            


     </dependencies>
            </plugin>           

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>

      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.companyA.xcert</groupId>
      <artifactId>XoShared</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.companyA.xcert</groupId>
      <artifactId>XoSigTprXch</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.companyA.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>XoTorque</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>torque</groupId>
            <artifactId>village</artifactId>
        </dependency>            
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>apache</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
       </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
      <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.evincible</groupId>
      <artifactId>EvncUtilCore</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.evincible</groupId>
      <artifactId>EvncJmx</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.evincible</groupId>
      <artifactId>EvncSdk</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.evincible</groupId>
      <artifactId>EvncPluginIfc</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.evincible</groupId>
      <artifactId>EvncAcFilter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.companyA.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>XoValidator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      </dependencies>`enter code here`
      </project>
```